# Alexa OAuth state property length change suddenely

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are suddenly receiving a change of '**State**' property length from below 1000 character to 1088 char.
Is there any fixed length of '**State**' property.
Can any one help me with this.

Thanks
Mohan

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The increase in the length of the ‘state’ parameter you observed is an expected behaviour, as the engineering team recently launched a new internal service which powers all the account linking experiences.

Furthermore, there is no defined length for the ‘state’ parameter at this point.